# When setting Build Action = Embedded resources in a resource file, "Insufficient system resources" error

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, embedded-resource

VS:2008 C# Winforms project, I am working on.

I added a file in resources and set its build action = Embedded Resources, then after I compiled the project, and an error occurred that insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service.

full description of Error:

> Could not write to output file '<>' -- 'Insufficient system resources exist to complete the requested service. '

Can anybody tell me why this error occured and how to resolve this issue?

Comment: thnx jonsca to correct the grammer

Comment: I presume there are indeed sufficient resources in your system? Disk space? You might want to bump up the build logging (Tools/Options/Projects and Solutions/Build and Run/MSBuild project build output verbosity) to detailed or diagnostic and try to get more information about the error.

Comment: fsimonazzi : i tried your suggestion, but visual studio doesn't providing more information on detailed or diagnostic mode also.

Comment: Look in the build tab of the output tool window.

Comment: for what i should look for ?

Comment: Look for any indication of an error. Maybe "error", or the name of the file. Look at the lines around and you might get some additional insight on the error.

Comment: I have allready done this type of work around, but i did'nt got any help.

Answer (score 0):

When i compile the project on local disk then it is compiled successfully.
but when i compile it on network drive the above mentioned error will generate.
I don't know how this error occures on network drive.

Comment: The network drive may be out of disk space. Check the drive that you're compiling to for free space and make sure it has enough.

Comment: yeh!.. network drive is connected and has 10 gb free space on it.